# Capture List and Function passed as argument in swift

Tags: swift

I have a function with this prototype:

`func myFunction(completionHandler:((response:[NSString:AnyObject])->Void)?))`

The `completionHandler` prototype can be passed as closure or as a function... passing it as closure I know how to define a capture list with this syntax `[weak self]`, but how can I define a capture list if instead of defining the closure directly in the function argument I want to pass a function name?

`myFunction(anotherFunction) // how to set capture list from here?`

VS

```
myFunction{ 
     [weak self] (response) in

}
```

```

EDIT-----

A possible solution is to wrap the function code into a block, set the capture list and execute the block... but it sounds so strange :/

```
myFunction(anotherFunction) // how to set capture list from here?
.
.
.
func anotherFunction(response:[NSString:AnyObject]) { 
    let safeBlock = { 
       [weak self] in { 
         self?.callSomethingSafely()
       }
    }

    safeBlock()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT (based on correction from Hamish below):

I'm not aware of a way to force a referenced method to internally use a weak version of a captured variable.  As you have in your example, it's up to to the actual method implementation to do that or not.

However, it's worth noting that unless you are going to be storing a reference to that completion handler indefinitely, you don't need to worry about weak self.

I assume that completion handler will be called as soon as some asynchronous task that `myFunction` kicks off is completed. In that case, any references captured by the completion handler will only be held until the completion handler runs. Then those references will be released and there won't be any retain cycles. Weak self in closures in only important if "self" retains the closure and the closure captures "self", setting up a circular reference / retain cycle.

Comment: "*the method has already been curried with a weakly captured reference to `someInstance`'s `self`*" – Do you have a source to back that up? AFAIK instance methods keep a strong reference to the instance they belong. If you keep a strong reference to a method of a given instance, that instance will not be deallocated.

Comment: @Hamish  You are absolutely correct and I have fixed my answer accordingly.  I created a test playground with an error in it that led me to a wrong assumption!

Comment: @DanielHall the application will crash if the view controller where `anotherFunction` is called is released. That's why I'm trying to avoid strong reference to `self` from that function. Edit: Actually the view controller cannot be released since the `anotherFunction` is creating a retaining cycle :/ uhm... it should not crash though.

Comment: @MatterGoal  Are you sure `anotherFunction` is creating a retain cycle? It seems like as soon as `myFunction` runs (which is immediately), the reference to the other closure or function would be released and so there wouldn't be any actual cycle.

Answer (score 1):

@[MatterGoal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499990/mattergoal) your solution will still produce a reference cycle.

I am assuming you are aware of the situations where we should use a capture list. For a scenario like `myFunction(anotherFunction)`, we cannot define a capture list for a method (`func`) named `anotherFunction` itself. At least for now, lets hope in future we can.

We can only define a capture for a closure. A method can act as a closure with same signature but it (method) does not support capture list for itself.

Solutions:

1. Make a `lazy var anotherFunction = { }` in which we can define capture list.
2. Make your function return a closure:

   ```
   func anotherFunction() -> (() -> Void) {
       return { [weak self] in
           // do anything you want with self? properties or methods.
           // this won't create a strong reference cycle
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Note the solution 2. will produce a new closure every time anotherFunction is called, duplicating the closure "object" in memory